# Array stores only one value instead of multiple

Tags: php, mysql

I could not figure out how to solve this:

Database:

```
+-------+-------------+------+
| id    | ArticleNr   | Size | 
+-------+-------------+------+
| 1     | AN111       | L    | 
| 2     | AN111       | XL   |
| 3     | AN222       | M    |
+-------+-------------+------+
```

```php
sql = "SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY article_number"
$result = $site_db->query($sql);
my_array = array();

while ($row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {
    $article_number = $row['article_number'];
    $size = $row['size'];
    $my_array[${'article_number'}] .= $row['size'];
}
```

As results I got this:

> **AN111**: L
>   **AN222**: M

However I want something like this:

> **AN111**: L - XL
>   **AN222**: M

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `group by` returns __single__ string for each article.

Comment: Thanks u_mulder. I have to use group by otherwise I will display all the double. Any suggestion?

Comment: What doubles will you display?

Comment: The article numbers

Comment: Article numbers are array keys, they can't be doubled.

Comment: I think it best to handle problems of data display such as this in your presentation layer - and I'd store sizes in a separate table, alongside a sequential id - because MySQL has no idea that L is larger than M.

Comment: Also, you have no column called article_number, and table is a reserved word

Comment: @ Strawberry
Hi. Gordon Linoff gave the solution. Thank you very much anyway. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think it's a poor solution compared with the alternative - but whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you want something like this:

```
SELECT article_number, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT size)
FROM table
GROUP BY article_number;
```

Unless you really, really, really know what you are doing, don't use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  It is not allowed in most other databases and is usually a sign of broken code.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Didn't work. It is still displaying 1x size. Do I have to add something else?

Comment: @SaraZ . . . Run this in phpadmin and see if the query is returning what you want.  It may be how you are reading the data.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you very much. 
There is an ohter problem. Now I get double in Sizes. If the same article has the same sizes.

Comment: I solve it using GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT size). Thank you very much for you help:)

Answer (score 1):

The returned value from the sql will be the first answer that matches the grouped article number if there are multiple entries for the article number, hence the returned `L`

I would ORDER BY `article_number` and forget the GROUP BY clause.

This would return all of the answers to the php parser

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY article_number"
$result = $site_db->query($sql);
$my_array = array();

$article_number = '';
$size = '';
while ($row = $site_db->fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['article_number']!=$article_number) {
    $article_number = $row['article_number'];
    $size = $row['size'];
    } else {
    $article_number = $row['article_number'];
    $size .= ' - '.$row['size'];
    }
    $my_array[$row['article_number']] = $row['size'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 ORDER 
    BY articlenr
     , FIELD(size,'XS','S','M','L','XL','XXL');
```

The rest of this problem can be solved with a simple PHP loop.